# Are there any alternatives to HBASE in particular with regards to key range scans?

Tags: nosql, hbase

The most relevant feature that I appreciate in HBASE is the key range scan, where you can combine your keys under a higher level key with lower level ones, which allows you to obtain a hierarchy of data related to the higher level keys.

For example:

```
CUSTOMER ID = C100
DEPARTMENT ID = D100
USER ID = U100
```

The key for the above example would be

```
C100D100U100K01 : "my data for k01"
C100D100U100K02 : "my data for k02"
C100D100U100K03 : "my data for k03"
...
```

With the above, you would be able to fetch all of the data related to your customer ID by performing a range scan on C100* or if more details where needed, by department such as C100D100U100*, and so on.

Are there any alternatives to HBASE with this regard in the NOSQL spectrum of solutions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any hierarchical key-value store would work.  There's a (short) list on Wikipedia : [Hierarchical key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Hierarchical_key.E2.80.93value_store).

The one I know best is [GT.M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GT.M), where your sample data could look like this :

```
customer("C100","D100","U100","K01")="my data for k01"
customer("C100","D100","U100","K02")="my data for k02"
customer("C100","D100","U100","K03")="my data for k03"
```

So `customer("C100")` would gives you access to all the data of a single customer, `customer("C100","D100")` would gives you access to all the data for a single department for a single customer, etc.

Comment: Good info on GT.M which I was not aware of. Unfortunately its licensing is a bit more restrictive on non Linux platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Couchbase has similar functionality if you use views (an index). You can create a view on all the keys, and do range queries over them. As far as I know, you can only wildcard over the end of a key but not the beginning, e.g.:

```
AAABBBCCCDDD* // yes
*BBBCCCDDDEEE // no
AAA*CCCDDDEEE // no
```

This is because it sorts the keys, and when you query you're getting a sub-range. However, you can get around this by creating views that sort by a different order.

More info: http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views.html

Answer (score 1):

Riak has secondary indexes that would allow querying data by matching the index or by range scan. The results from secondary indexes can be used as an input for Riak's MapReduce. Check this for more details: [riak secondary indexes](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/tutorials/querying/Secondary-Indexes/)